# Strange error trying to run ember tests on debian linux

Tags: linux, testing, ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing

All our tests pass on multiple macOS machines, and on semaphore-ci, but when we try to build and run tests on a new debian box, we get this error in loader.js:143

```
not ok 1320 Chrome 72.0 - TestLoader Failures: zipbooks/tests/unit/utils/request-log-test: could not be loaded
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        stack: >
            TypeError: Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
                at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)
                at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)
                at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)
                at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)
                at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)
                at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)
                at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)
                at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)
                at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)
                at requireModule (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:32:18)
        message: >
            Died on test #1     at TestLoader.moduleLoadFailure (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:11150:24)
                at TestLoader.<anonymous> (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10463:16)
                at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10451:27)
                at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10443:16)
                at loadTests (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:11174:22)
                at start (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10857:33)
                at Module.callback (http://localhost:45371/assets/tests.js:20710:25): Cannot read property 'exports' of undefined
        Log: |
            { type: 'info',
              text: '\'Unit assertion failed and test has been paused for inspection.\'\n' }
            { type: 'error',
              text: '{ module: \'TestLoader Failures\',\n  name: \'zipbooks/tests/unit/utils/request-log-test: could not be loaded\',\n  result: false,\n  message: \'Died on test #1     at TestLoader.moduleLoadFailure (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:11150:24)\\n    at TestLoader.<anonymous> (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10463:16)\\n    at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10451:27)\\n    at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10443:16)\\n    at loadTests (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:11174:22)\\n    at start (http://localhost:45371/assets/test-support.js:10857:33)\\n    at Module.callback (http://localhost:45371/assets/tests.js:20710:25): Cannot read property \\\'exports\\\' of undefined\',\n  actual: null,\n  testId: \'8629d10a\',\n  negative: false,\n  runtime: 1,\n  todo: false,\n  source: \'TypeError: Cannot read property \\\'exports\\\' of undefined\\n    at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)\\n    at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)\\n    at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)\\n    at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)\\n    at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)\\n    at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)\\n    at Module._reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:148:59)\\n    at Module.reify (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:135:27)\\n    at Module.exports (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:109:10)\\n    at requireModule (http://localhost:45371/assets/vendor.js:32:18)\' }\n' }
```

We cannot find any information or have any guesses what might be causing this error.

```
ember-cli: 3.1.4
node: 8.5.0
os: linux x64
```

The pattern I'm seeing is that any test that uses `setupTest`, `setupApplicationTest` or `setupRenderingTest` is failing. Regular qunit tests that dont have any setup hooks pass fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your dependencies are the same? This sounds like different versions of dependencies or sub-dependencies to me.

Comment: We ran `yarn install` with the same package.json. I'm not sure what could be different.

Comment: You need to have the same `yarn.lock` in order to get the same version of dependencies and sub-dependencies. Only sharing the same `package.json` does not guarantee a deterministic build.

Comment: The first thing I look at when getting different tests in different environments is `config/targets.js`. The default switches build targets based on an environmental variable `CI`. The last few times we were seeing weird tests in one place it was because this variables was set there (or something else was effecting the environment at build time). You may also want to run `ember build` in both locations and then check the output for difference.

Comment: Lock file is in git and we’ve played with targets and set CI. The diffing build output is a fantastic idea. I’ll follow up with reaults

Comment: ok so `ember build --test` definitely produces a different `dist` folder. But I can't figure out what could be different. Exact same node version, exact same ember version

Comment: `yarn list` results are identical. This is so bizarre. It's definitely using different versions of the packages though because the build out put is obviously different

Comment: I zippped up and pulled down node_modules and in all the important ways, the entire directories are identical. How could `ember build --test` be producing such different results when node_modules is exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not installing the yarn dependencies in our in-repo addon

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is binary dependencies that are platform-specific.  Have you tried running `npm rebuild` first?  Certain dependencies (such as node-sass) use binaries that are platform-specific, and need to be rebuilt.  If that's your issue, if you ever need to do this in an automated fashion, you'll want to limit the scope of the rebuild to only the necessary dependencies, e.g. `npm rebuild some-package some-other-package` rather than the all inclusive `npm rebuild`

Unfortunately, `yarn` has yet to implement the rebuild feature, so we've moved back to `npm`, for that and other reasons. -- [link to issue in GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5271)

Comment: darn. I'm not sure thats it. I cleared out node_modules and installed with npm and run npm rebuild and same error :(